# fn_dblog not showing records while LDF file is large

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I need to find some specific transactions in the transactionlog file, so I use fn_dblog function. But the function is only returning a few rows. Meanwhile the LDF file for my database is a couple of gigabytes at least.

I know the fn_dblog function is only searching the active part of the log:

- But what does that mean?
- When does a part of the transactionlog becomes inactive?
- And how can I search the inactive part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference:

[SQL Server Transaction Log Architecture and Management Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-log-architecture-and-management-guide)

> I know the fn_dblog function is only searching the active part of the
>   log: But what does that mean?

**Active Log**

The section of the log file from the MinLSN to the last-written log record is called the active portion of the log, or the active log. This is the section of the log required to do a full recovery of the database. No part of the active log can ever be truncated. All log records must be truncated from the parts of the log before the MinLSN.

The following illustration shows a simplified version of the end-of-a-transaction log with two active transactions. Checkpoint records have been compacted to a single record.

[image]

LSN 148 is the last record in the transaction log. At the time that the recorded checkpoint at LSN 147 was processed, Tran 1 had been committed and Tran 2 was the only active transaction. That makes the first log record for Tran 2 the oldest log record for a transaction active at the time of the last checkpoint. This makes LSN 142, the Begin transaction record for Tran 2, the MinLSN.

> When does a part of the transactionlog becomes inactive?

In the above example as soon as Checkpoint (LSN147) happens LSN141 portion becomes inactive. SQL server manages these in chunks of Virtual Log File (called VLF).

[What the VLF](https://mikehillwig.com/2013/05/10/what-the-vlf/) by Mike Hillwig

In general, Log truncation occurs automatically after the following events, except when delayed for some reason:

- Under the simple recovery model, after a checkpoint.
- Under the full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model, after a
  log backup, if a checkpoint has occurred since the previous backup.

> And how can I search the inactive part?

I am not aware of any documented Microsoft process of doing that. Paul Randal shows an undocumented process called `fn_dump_dblog` in [this](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) article.

There are 3rd party products you can use.

One of those here:

https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

Answer (score 5):

the overall issue with your endeavor, while I commend it, is that *getting* the log isn't the hard part. **Reading** the log is, as it isn't documented at all. There are 3rd party products that can help you, but you reading the log and asking these questions isn't going to work out very well. This wasn't written to put you off, merely to express that the log isn't very human readable, documented, or otherwise made for people to go slogging through it.

With that, the below should help you:

> I know the fn_dblog function is only searching the active part of the log:

Unless you set the proper trace flag. I'm not going to reinvent the wheel, here, Paul already has a [great post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) on this.

> •But what does that mean?

It means without the TF it won't look at inactive parts of the log... [inactive VLFs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-log-architecture-and-management-guide)

> •When does a part of the transactionlog becomes inactive?

When it's not longer needed by recovery (and/or, depending on recovery model) when it's been successfully backed up. See the log architecture link, above.

> •And how can I search the inactive part?

See Paul's blog.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running in either `FULL` or `BULK-LOGGED` recovery mode and referencing [Transaction Log Truncation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085(v=sql.105).aspx):

> Under the full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model, the
>   inactive part of the log cannot be truncated until all its log records
>   have been captured in a log backup. This is needed to maintain the log
>   chain—a series of log records having an unbroken sequence of log
>   sequence numbers (LSNs). The log is truncated when you back up the
>   transaction log, assuming the following conditions exist:
>
> - A checkpoint has occurred since the log was last backed up. A    checkpoint is essential but not sufficient for truncating the log
>     under the full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model. After a
>     checkpoint, the log remains intact at least until the next
>     transaction log backup.
> - No other factor is preventing log transaction.
>     Generally, with regular backups, log space is regularly freed for future use. However, various factors, such as a long-running transaction, can temporarily prevent log truncation. For more information, see [Factors That Can Delay Log Truncation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414(v=sql.105).aspx)
> - Generally, with regular backups, log space is regularly freed for    future use. However, various factors, such as a long-running
>     transaction, can temporarily prevent log truncation. For more
>     information, see Factors That Can Delay Log Truncation.
> - The BACKUP LOG statement does not specify WITH COPY_ONLY.

As to your question about "*And how can I search the inactive part?*", there is an extensive article [Read SQL Server Transaction Log Backups to Find When Transactions Occurred](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3555/read-sql-server-transaction-log-backups-to-find-when-transactions-occurred/) that shows you how to use the undocumented command `fn_dump_dblog()` to find the data in a SQL Server Transaction Log Backup.

Comment: I am aware of the `fn_dump_dblog()` function but the client has some special backup software. They cannot give me the backup files directly, they can only restore directly to a SQL Server. But that does not restore the 'active' transaction log.

Answer (score 1):

There is another case here that might be relevant.  While your database might be using a Full Recovery model, if you’ve never backed up your database, you are still in a Simple Recovery model.  In this model, you might not be able to find the transaction you’re looking for because it’s been over written.  The Full Recovery model doesn’t actually take effect until a log chain is started and this happens when the database is backed up.